# How to do Bootstrap's documentation sub-navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting to get into Twitter-Bootstrap to help me get started making web applications. I'm liking what I see so far, but I'm wanting to have a subnavigation thing similar to how their documentation does.

For instance, at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html there is a sub navigation bar. I really like how it magically sticks to the top when you scroll past it. Also, I like the styling a bit more than the regular `nav-pills`

I can't quite figure out what all causes this effect though. And I'm a bit scared away by this comment in their javascript:

```
// NOTICE!! DO NOT USE ANY OF THIS JAVASCRIPT
// IT'S ALL JUST JUNK FOR OUR DOCS!
```

Answer (score 2):

While I didn't utilize the javascript, I did pull their CSS to create my own subnav bar on a bootstrap app i threw together.  The relevant CSS for `.subnav` is in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css

Their warning just means that the javascript was not written for public consumption, so it may not be fully tested or written nicely. However, this is the javascript for fixing the subnav bar on scroll:

```
// fix sub nav on scroll
var $win = $(window)
  , $nav = $('.subnav')
  , navTop = $('.subnav').length && $('.subnav').offset().top - 40
  , isFixed = 0

processScroll()

// hack sad times - holdover until rewrite for 2.1
$nav.on('click', function () {
  if (!isFixed) setTimeout(function () {  $win.scrollTop($win.scrollTop() - 47) }, 10)
})

$win.on('scroll', processScroll)

function processScroll() {
  var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop()
  if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) {
    isFixed = 1
    $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed')
  } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) {
    isFixed = 0
    $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed')
  }
}
```

Basically, when the window scrolls, this code checks to see if the subnav bar has reached the top of the window; if it has, the `subnav-fixed` class is added and a flag is set. otherwise, the class is removed and the flag set to false

Comment: Bootstrap changed its documentation in v2, so the .subnav CSS is no longer included. Any other sources?